# Cannot find file .exe

Tags: c++, data-loss

When I compile my project Visual Studio says it is unable to find the .exe file. I assume this is because the program is unable to compile. I have fixed most of the bugs that I had but I can't figure out what remains.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Hmwk.3.Assignment, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  engine.cpp
1>c:\users\tmars_000\desktop\hmwk.3.released\engine.cpp(23): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'elements'
1>c:\users\tmars_000\desktop\hmwk.3.released\engine.cpp(29): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\tmars_000\desktop\hmwk.3.released\engine.cpp(30): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm not sure how to format the Block** in a way to fix the error.

```
//Engine.cpp
include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "engine.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include "Opponent.h"

using namespace std;
fstream fin; 

void loadBackground(std::string gameFile, int & numElements, Block**& elements){

    int tempX;
    int tempY;

    fin.open(gameFile,ios::in);

    fin >> numElements;
    Block** elements = new Block*[numElements];

    for(int i=0; i<numElements; i++){
        elements[i] = new Block();
        fin >> tempX;
        fin >> tempY;
        elements[i]->setPosX(tempX);
        elements[i]->setPosY(tempY);
    }
    fin.close();
}


void changeGameState(std::string command, Player* player, Opponent* opponent){

    player->update(command);
    opponent->update(command);

}
```

When I change it to simply elements = new Block*[numElements]; it created these errors.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Hmwk.3.Assignment, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  engine.cpp
1>c:\users\tmars_000\desktop\hmwk.3.released\engine.cpp(25): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\tmars_000\desktop\hmwk.3.released\engine.cpp(26): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>Opponent.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_fstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > fin" (?fin@@3V?$basic_fstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@A) already defined in engine.obj
1>Player.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::basic_fstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > fin" (?fin@@3V?$basic_fstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@A) already defined in engine.obj
1>gui.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Opponent::getSpriteID(void)" (?getSpriteID@Opponent@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall GUI::displayGameState(class Player *,class Opponent *,int,class Block * *)" (?displayGameState@GUI@@QAEXPAVPlayer@@PAVOpponent@@HPAPAVBlock@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\tmars_000\Desktop\Hmwk.3.Released\Debug\Hmwk.3.Assignment.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Are these related to the format of that line, or are they likely separate issues only appearing after it compiles that line?

Comment: The compile error comes from the fact that you have 2 variables with the same name (elements): the last parameter of the function, and an other variable that you declare later. Probably you just meant `elements = new Block*[numElements];`, but it's hard to tell without more context.

Comment: When I change it to that, it creates several new errors that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure another answer will go more in-depth with this, but the short version is exactly what the error says:

```
void loadBackground(std::string gameFile, int & numElements, Block**& elements){ //elements is being defined as a parameter name

    int tempX;
    int tempY;

    fin.open(gameFile,ios::in);

    fin >> numElements;
    Block** elements = new Block*[numElements]; //ERROR: elements is being redefined

    for(int i=0; i<numElements; i++){
        elements[i] = new Block();
        fin >> tempX;
        fin >> tempY;
        elements[i]->setPosX(tempX);
        elements[i]->setPosY(tempY);
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

So you can rename `elements`.

Comment: He probably wanted to assign the allocated array to the elements parameter (as an output to the function).

Comment: Hmm... But what I need to do is create a dynamic array of Block objects that is pointed to by elements in main. I declare it in main and pass it to the constructor. How do I maintain that pointer as I create the array of blocks so that I can use it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that you told it twice what `elements` is, therefore the error. To fix it just substitute

```
Block** elements = new Block*[numElements];
```

for:

`elements = new Block*[numElements];`

If I understood correctly, you are trying to allocate memory and use the pointer that was passed as argument to point to it. That's exactly what this does.